# 'cannot find module' issue in renderer process in Electron app build for the win32 with electron-packager

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm working on Electron app.
I use following command to build for win32:

```
electron-packager ./app/ feb  --prune --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite=true
```

Building process completes well, without errors.
The build for darwin works well without any errors. But build for win32 throws `cannot find module` errors in console. Errors related to the local files I try to require:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './config/menu.js'
```

Here it is `./config/menu.js` file content:

```
var config = {}

config.window = {
  title:        'App Name',
  width:        950,
  height:       800,
  show:         true,
  center:       true
}

module.exports = config
```

and here it is how I require it from the `renderer.js`:

```
var menuTemplate = require('./config/menu')
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but seems like you need to use `path.resolve()` method.
For more info, check [this](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)